# Spyder: libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found & failed to load driver: swrast

Tags: centos7, spyder

I'm trying to run spyder from anaconda 3.7 on CentOS7. I get the error;

> libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
>   libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/labs/training/student9/.drirc: No such file or directory.
>   libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
>   libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>   function is no-op
>   Unrecognized OpenGL version
>   Unrecognized OpenGL version

/usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so, exist:

> ll /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
>   -rwxr-xr-x 8 root root 11038656 Apr 11  2018 /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
>
> rpm -qf /usr/lib64/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
>   mesa-dri-drivers-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
>
> rpm -qa | grep nvidia

return nothing

any clue how this problem can solved?

Answer (score 0):

I install spyder from [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/).
 Now  it open the spyder window
(with the error)